# Bind ObservableCollection to ComboBox in DataGrid is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I have ready many articles which covers binding Observable Collection to ComboBox but I stil can't figure it out why my collection isn't bindng to ComboBox placed in DataGrid.

My Model

```
class DDV 
{

    public DDV(int ID, string Naziv)
    {
        _ID = ID;
        _Naziv = Naziv;
    }

    private int _ID;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set { _ID = value; }
    }

    private string _Naziv;
    public string Naziv
    {
        get { return _Naziv; }
        set { _Naziv = value; }
    }
```

My ViewModel:

```
class ArtikliStoritveViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ArtikliStoritveViewModel()
    {
        DDVData.Add(new DDV(1, "Ceka"));
        DDVData.Add(new DDV(2, "Zeka"));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DDV> _DDVData = new ObservableCollection<DDV>();
    public ObservableCollection<DDV> DDVData
    {
        get
        {
            return this._DDVData;
        }

        set
        {
            _DDVData = value;
        }
    }
```

DataContext:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ArtikliStoritveViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Binding:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox
                            x:Name="cmbDDV"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding DDVData}"
                            DisplayMemberPath="Naziv"
                        />
                        </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I have observable collection in View model:

```
    private ObservableCollection<DDV> _DDVData = new ObservableCollection<DDV>();
    public ObservableCollection<DDV> DDVData
    {
        get
        {
            return this._DDVData;
        }

        set
        {
            _DDVData = value;
        }
    }
```

My DataGrid Bind to tihs View Model:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ArtikliStoritveData}
```

In constructor in View model I bind to collection:

```
    DDV _ddv;
    public ArtikliStoritveViewModel()
    {
        _ddv = new DDV { ID = 1, Naziv = "Ceka" };
        DDVData.Add(_ddv);
    }
```

So everything must stay in this View Model.

What else I have to do to make this work. Currently nothing is binding.

Regards,
Igor

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in your data model. What is available to your `DataTemplate` is an instance of your `DDV` class and that has no collection property named `DDVData` to data bind to. Instead, you need to add a collection to your `DDV` class that you can data bind to the `ComboBox` in each row of the `DataGrid` and then data bind the collection property named `DDVData` from the view model to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionPropertyInViewModel}">
    ...
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbDDV"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionPropertyInModelClass}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Naziv" />
                    </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Incidentally, if you had looked in your Output Window in Visual Studio, you should have seen some errors saying something like *there is no property named `DDVData` found in object `DDV`* or something like that... helpful clues.

---

UPDATE >>>

I updated the code above to make it clearer. With your information that you just provided, you'd need to do this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DDVData}">
    ...
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbDDV"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ArtikliStoritveData}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Naziv" />
                    </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

This will work when:

1. The `DataGrid` is in the `Window` that has the `ArtikliStoritveViewModel` instance set as its `DataContext`
2. The `DDVData` property is in the `ArtikliStoritveViewModel`
3. The `DDV` class has a collection property declared in it named `ArtikliStoritveData`

If that is *not* the case, then this won't work. You said *I have some other Observable Collection in Model View, so I can not change it to DDVDData in DDV model*... I have no idea what you mean by *Model View*, but if you set the `Window.DataContext` to an instance of you `ArtikliStoritveViewModel`, the *that* is what it has access to. So, you'll either need to add the collection into the `DDV` class, or the `ArtikliStoritveViewModel` class.

Comment: I have some other Observable Collection in Model View, so I can not change it to DDVDData in DDV model:

        public ObservableCollection<ArtikliStoritve> ArtikliStoritveData
        {
            get { return _artikliStoritveData; }
            set
            {
                _artikliStoritveData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ArtikliStoritveData");
            }
        }

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ArtikliStoritveData}"

Comment: Please add your code to the end of your *question* and *not* in a *comment*, where it is difficult to see. Also, I didn't really understand what you said.

Comment: I added. I don't have any errors or warnings in Output window.

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial? http://tech.pro/tutorial/742/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1

Comment: I figure it out. Observable collection DDVData must be added to Observable colletion which data grid binds to.